# Apt-get failed to update on 12.10

Tags: apt, 12.10, software-center, official-repositories

When running a software update, I got a message telling me that either my network connections aren't working anymore, or that Failed to download repository information.  I already tried restarting my computer and running the software updater from the terminal. I am running Xubuntu 12.10.

`sudo apt-get update` gives me the following output: 
sorry for the long list from the terminal and thank you

```
sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for bob: 

Ign http:/extras.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease                         
Hit http:/extras.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg                            
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates InRelease                  
Hit http:/extras.ubuntu.com quantal Release   
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports InRelease
Ign http:/security.ubuntu.com quantal-security InRelease             
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg
Hit http:/extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main Sources
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release.gpg
Hit http:/extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main i386 Packages
Ign http:/security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release.gpg
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release.gpg
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release
Ign http:/security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release           
Ign http:/extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-he_IL          
Ign http:/extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-he             
Ign http:/extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en
Err http:/security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http:/security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http:/security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http:/security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http:/security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http:/security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http:/security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http:/security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Ign http:/security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-he_IL
Ign http:/security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-he
Ign http:/security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en
Ign http:/security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-he_IL
Ign http:/security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-he
Ign http:/security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http:/security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-he_IL
Ign http:/security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-he
Ign http:/security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http:/security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-he_IL
Ign http:/security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-he
Ign http:/security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-en
Err http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-he_IL
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-he
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-he_IL
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-he
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-he_IL
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-he
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-en
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-he_IL
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-he
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en
Err http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-he_IL
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-he
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-he_IL
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-he
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-he_IL
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-he
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-he_IL
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-he
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en
Err http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Translation-he_IL
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Translation-he
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Translation-en
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Translation-he_IL
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Translation-he
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Translation-he_IL
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Translation-he
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Translation-en
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Translation-he_IL
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Translation-he
Ign http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http:/security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http:/security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http:/security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http:/security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http:/security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http:/security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http:/security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http:/security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http:/il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: sudo apt-get update says the same as above in the firs question

Comment: for example i tried to install vlc from the terminal and i received 
: bob@bob:~$ sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc
[sudo] password for bob: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package browser-plugin-vlc

Answer (score 5):

Xubuntu 12.10 is no longer supported, it hit End-of-Life. The deprecated packages are taken down after 12 months, so it seems time has come.

To make apt-get update work, you simply need to edit /etc/apt/sources.list and update all URLs from security.ubuntu.com and archive.ubuntu.com to point to old-releases.ubuntu.com, as per the following sed command:

`sudo sed -i.bak -r 's/(archive|security).ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list`

If you want to upgrade your system you can use following commands:

`sudo apt-get install update-manager-core && do-release-upgrade`

Comment: I would recommend `sudo apt-get install update-manager-core && do-release-upgrade` so the second command is only performed if the first one works.

Comment: the first one did not work so i did the second one and it did updated but still do not work
now it says:
Package dependencies cannot be resolved

This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

Comment: Try to remove conflicted packages (e.g. `vlc`) and reinstall them again after upgrade

Comment: i do not have installed vlc

Comment: try this: `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: except of eraseing your last comment is stay the same

in the terminal:
bob@bob:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt-get install -f
[sudo] password for bob: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for bob: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.5.0-17 linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: You can add outputs to you question, not posts them in comments. Also, what `sudo apt-get update` says now?

Comment: The script didn't work for me, cause in my case the address was _"us.archive.ubuntu.com"_ instead of _"archive.ubuntu.com"_. But manually replacing all the sources with _"old-releases.ubuntu.com"_ saved my _Vagrant + Puppet_ Box! :)